# function in setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

There are two functions hello1() and hello2().

```
function hello1(){
    console.log('hello1');
}

function hello2(){
    console.log('hello2');
}

setTimeout(hello1, 3000);
setTimeout(hello2(), 3000);
```

In `setTimeout(hello1, 3000);`, it print "hello1" after delay 3 seconds.

But in `setTimeout(hello2(), 3000);`, it print "hello2" immediately.

I think it's because it must use function name in setTimeout.

What if I want to execute a function with parameters after delay 3 seconds like `hello(1)`?

Because I want to deliver parameters into function so I can't just only use function name in setTimeout like `setTimeout(hello1, 3000);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use parenthesis for the function in `setTimeout` it is executed immediately.

To use function with parameters, you can use anynomous function as timeout function and call your function inside it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    hello(1, 'param');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem :)