# Passing parameters to the function in setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function in a cycle with `setTimeout()`, and also pass the counter as a parameter. Here's what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>

<button onclick="timed1()">Display alerts</button>

<script>
function timed1() {
 for (i=1; i<4; i++){
  setTimeout(
     (function(i){ alert(i) })(i), 1000*i
   );
 }
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

Function calls are done with correct values, but immediately instead of the intervals I wanted. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195140/function-in-settimeout-doesnt-work) SO questions but unfortunately don't see yet what should I change in my case.

Comment: man that line is so unreadable

Comment: So you are executing the function and assigning what it returns to the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `let` here if you want to bind different values of `i` to the setTimeout function

```js
function timed1() {
    for (let i=1; i<4; i++){
      setTimeout(function() { 
          alert(i) 
      }, 1000*i)
    }
}
timed1()
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(function(i){ alert(i) })(i)` does not return a function for `setTimeout` to call. If you're going the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) way, make sure to return a new function from it:

```
setTimeout((function(i) {
    return function() {
        alert(i);
    };
})(i), 1000 * i);
```

---

With ES2015+ a far better readable equivalent can be realized:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => alert(i), 1000 * i);
}
```

Comment: thank you @Jeffrey! (in my case, I'll take mehulmpt's solution for its easier readability, but I learned important piece from yours)

Comment: That's fine :) I have added a more readable equivalent, just for fun.

Comment: awesome, thanks! I'm only starting to learn arrow functions :)

Answer (score 1):

You're swimming on [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

You're calling your function immediately.

```
setTimeout(
   (function(i){ alert(i) })(i), 1000*i
);                           ^
```

The scope of your variable `i` is open, you need to use `let` keyword.

```
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
     ^
```

## Look at this code snippet

```js
function timed1() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        alert(i)
      }, 1000 * i);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="timed1()">Display alerts</button>
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` function allows you to pass arguments to the callback function, like so:

```js
function timed1() {
  for (i=1; i<4; i++){
    setTimeout(alert, 1000 * i, i);
  }
}

timed1()
```

Any arguments after the time are passed along to the callback.

Comment: ah, that's very neat! didn't think about passing the arguments that way, thank you!